# Using unity in many applications

Tags: unity-game-engine

It has been a while that I'm developing some games with unity3d and now I want to upgrade my free plan to a plus or a pro one but I need some information before doing that.

first, if I create 3 apps that use the same unity player, same unity code but different android code for example and I publish them to the store , then I want to update one without touching unity player (just updating the android side such as a web view ) after canceling my subscription is that possible ?

second, is there more information about unity enterprise ?!

finally , there is no way to pay one single payment (not 1 year) to use unity pro or plus ?

Comment: I think that you should ask this questions in the unity3d forums pal. Anyway, as a unity3d developer I totally encourage you to start with the free version, and if you really feel you need the pro version move into it.

Comment: 1. For first question, you should get subscription to do that. cuz anything you modified android code, you need build all source code using Unity3D to make apk. but if you don't care about splash screen or any feature of pro plan than you can build it without subscription.

2. Check this site for second question.
    https://store.unity.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answers , @BrianChoi for the first question what if I pay untiy , finish building my app , change the splash screen then publish it . after that I unsubscribe so I don't pay no more . would I still can update my app without touching the unity side ?

Comment: @trfalgarlaw Officially, You can not update without unity because of you need to rebuild it. but when you build unity as project for android it might be possible to build in android studio but i haven't tried yet so. As I know, you can not build without changing splash screen as default in unsubscription state.

Comment: @BrianChoi so basically , if I add unity to a different existing android projects when I have the unity pro license , publish my apps to the store and then unsubscribe from unity pro  , I would be able to update my android code without touching unity and unity screen will keep the pro features right ?!

Comment: @trfalgarlaw
In BuildSettings, there is 'Export Project' option for android. so if you do that when you have pro license. You can only modify android code.

Comment: @BrianChoi Thank you very much ! is it the same for iOS ?

Comment: @trfalgarlaw yeah, Unity export xcode for ios, but Usually, I haven't tried modifying code like you do.

Comment: @BrianChoi Got it ! thanks man